# get PHP to compile ant release's safely

Tags: centos, security, compilation, apache

On CentOS I would like to give the `apache` user permissions to "ant release" on a home dir it does not own how do I do that? the `ant release` I am using is as part of the android SDK - I have a dir `/home/myuser/android_project/` and `ant relase` runs fine from there but I would like to give `apache` the permissions it needs to run it so I can run as as

```
<?php  shell_exec('/home/myuser/android_project/ant release') ?>.
```

The gotcha

Also there is an issue since I sign the `ant release` I would like to have the password handled perhaps in a file that php can somehow magically "sign" the `ant release`.

Now.

Note: to `Mr Tinker`: Hold the horses - I know that this is might fall foul of the forum topic police, but in my considered opinion it is a `unix issue`. i.e. I know how PHP does shell_exec I need no programming help. I know how to run `ant release` manually so I need no installation help:  I would like to sew together these two disparate manual "things" within linux (the CentOS server) so I believe 100% this is a unix issue

Comment: Your reasoning behind thinking this is not offtopic is wrong. This same issue would be present if you were running the code on a windows system. This is a programming question.

Comment: should not have been moved as it is architecture related: good grief - and as an aside NO this would NOT appear on windows at all! Windows has no such operation permissions!

Answer (score 0):

As you've already stated, you need to give the apache user permission to execute the `/home/myuser/android_project/ant` file.

tl;dr : run the following command (be warned, it might not be the most secure thing in the world):

```
chmod 777 /home/myuser/android_project/ant
```

---

If you're interested in why this might fix your problem, continue to read below.

First, you need to get some more information.
Run the following command:

```
ls -l /home/myuser/android_project/ant
```

The `ls -l` command will give you the read, write, and execute permissions for the specified file, along with the ownership information. The first column contains the permission information. The 3rd column indicates the owning user, and the 4th column indicates the owning group.

For example:

```
$ ls -l /etc/passwd
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2177 Aug 26 21:23 /etc/passwd
       ^^^
        |----------- All Users & Groups
    ^^^
     |-------------- Specified Group Owner
^^^
 |------------------ Specified User Owner
```

This can be interpreted as user root and group root owning the `/etc/passwd` file.
The permissions are read as groups of 3 `rwx` characters. The first group is for owning user, the 2nd for owning group, and the 3rd for everyone else on the system. The permissions in this example mean that the root user can read and write to the file, the root group can read, and everyone else can read.

Now, each group of permissions can be represented as an octal digit:

```
--- == 0
--x == 1
-w- == 2
-wx == 3
r-- == 4
r-x == 5
rw- == 6
rwx == 7
```

You now have enough information to understand why the `chmod 777` command above worked. Basically you will have given everyone on the system permission to read, write, and execute that ant file.

Ideally, you would only give the minimum permissions required to allow apache to execute the file, I'll leave that much as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question and you should not recommend 777 perms.

Comment: I think *you're* misunderstanding the question and I clearly put a disclaimer about chmod 777.

Comment: I really don't want to 777 it I want to chown and belong to the right member group